# Postgres - order from newest to oldest - no timestamp

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to list entries from the table in **descending**(based in when it was created) order given that I don't have timestamp or any dates/times in the table itself? All of the examples I found use `order by timestamp`.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to order by something you dont have - interesting.

Comment: If you don't have anything to order by then you can't order it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to *order* (aka *sort*) query results, you need to have something to sort on.  If you don't have a timestamp, that is difficult to do.

However, many tables have hidden ID fields, called `oid`.  It is a unique identifier, which may be the best you can hope for:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(
  name text
  ) WITH (oids);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES ('John'),('Jacob'),('Jingle-Heimer'),('Schmitt');


SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY oid;
```

You're at the mercy of what the *oid* value is and if the field even exists.  If your database configuration is to create this by default, you may not have needed to specify it during table creation.

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d9ad5/5)

Comment: There is also `xmin` column - the transaction ID where row was inserted/updated... `order by xmin::text::int`

Answer (score 0):

If your data has an automatically-generated index column, then you can sort on that in descending order to (roughly) return entries in the reverse order from which they were added.

It's not an ideal solution, since it makes certain assumptions as to how the indices are generated, but it's probably the closest that you can manage without actually adding a time stamp.

If you don't have an index column either, then the default sort order *should* return the entries in the order that they were added to the database, though that's even less reliable, and you'll have to apply the reverse-sorting manually afterwards in whichever language you are using to retrieve / display the data.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "default sort order".

Comment: Sure there is.  It's the order in which it returns the rows if you don't sort them at all.

Comment: But that is no defined order. It can change between queries any time without notice. Even two different sessions could get a different order depending on the execution plan.

Comment: That's why I said it's very unreliable and shouldn't be used.